# Is striped bass suited for sous vide?

Tags: fish, sous-vide

I have to cook some striped bass tomorrow. It is from frozen, and in fillets  with no skin (if it had skin I would pan sear it, but alas it doesn't). I was thinking, season with salt, pepper, and smoked paprika. Then sous vide @ 135, then serve it on a romesco sauce. I am fairly unfamiliar with striped bass and was wondering how well it is sous vide. Sous vide would be very advantageous, since I need to make a lot (serve 10), and don't want to stink up the house.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you are asking whether people like sous vide bass or your proposed seasoning blend then this question is opinion based and therefore off topic. Are you looking to understand the sous vide method or the amount of time to cook it?

Comment: Pretty much if striped bass is suitable for sous-vide. The other info is just to give context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use sous vide as a tool in the kitchen on a regular basis. Over the years I've developed some preferences and recognize that as a tool, there are some jobs it does well, and other jobs where traditional cooking methods simply produce a better result.  For me, I prefer fish cooked using traditional methods, and I would use the stove, oven, or grill before I chose sous vide.  Having said that, striped bass works better sous vide that many other varieties.  It is firm and fairly forgiving.  So, your plan is reasonable.  A brief brine could help maintain the texture, if that is something you are interested in. There are numerous recipes on the internets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the confirmation. It came out great. If it had skin I definitely would have gone traditional, but this way worked and was much less stressful.